# mysql regexp varchar value which contains \0

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm testing the regexp feature, and I met a problem. The sql statement likes:

```
SELECT field FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^[a-z][a-z0-9\\.]*[a-z0-9]$' LIMIT 1;
```

It matches a row, however that field contains more that the a-z0-9. characters. in hex, the value is:

```
61 726d 0000 00ab 003f 3f00
```

I want to let such rows filtered out.  What's the correct sql statement I can write?

Comment: I don't exactly understand -  you said your current expression matches a row, does it or does it not match the value which terminates in `0x00`? Do you want to exclude the ones which terminate in `0x00` while keeping everything currently matched by your regex?

Comment: Are you sure it is not ucs-2 (Unicode)?  If it is, then the right solution would be to convert the `CHARACTER SET`.

Comment: the database is utf8 encoded and the "field" is varchar.  And I suspect that the REGEXP matched the first three char, so it returned true. It seems not to be concerned about the data after 00.

Comment: An idea comes to me that if we can get the REGEXP matched chars' length, then I can filter the bad data out by comparing the LENGTH(field) and the length the regexp matched.  Is there such a solution?

Comment: at last I found a temp way by add a "AND CHAR_LENGTH(field) = LENGTH(field)" at the end of where conditions.